# Download file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to download a SWF file using Python,
but for some reason everytime I use urllib.urlretrieve(url,filepathwithname) or wget.download(url), it says:

```
File "C:\Users\User-PC\Desktop\check.py", line 3, in <module>
response = 
urllib.urlretrieve('www.domain.com\\folder\\folder\\52sd1399sc2emaple-story-
vthree-f.swf','file.swf')
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
fp = self.open(url, data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 469, in open_file
return self.open_local_file(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 483, in open_local_file
raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the path specified: 
'www.domain.com\\folder\\folder\\52sd1399sc2emaple-story-vthree-f.swf'
```

while the wget line still gives the same error when running the line in a seperate file than my code(which runs perfectly without that download line), it does work sometimes, but wget never works with the swf links I've placed.

***Note**. The string I enter is "www.domain.com\folder\folder\52sd1399sc2emaple-story-vthree-f.swf" and the error contains "www.domain.com\folder\folder\52sd1399sc2emaple-story-vthree-f.swf".

Please help.

Comment: Try changing backslashes to forward slashes.

Comment: @lancew been there, tried that, still doesn't work :( Thanks for commenting!

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Comment: please show us your piece that code. so we can see it.

Comment: Your supposed URL is in fact not a URL at all. Try making it valid: `'http://www.example.com/whatever.swf'`. Your current code is trying to open a local file in the `www.domain.com` folder, which unsurprisingly doesn't exist.

Comment: @Blckknght but the address of the file is under a couple of folders. when I enter the address by my self on chrome it gets to the file I'm willing to download.

Comment: Your web browser may fill in the `http://` part of the URL for you, but `urllib` will not. In this situation, the protocol part of the URL is not optional (nor is it optional to use the right kind of slash). Stack Overflow won't let me write out your full URL in a comment (it says to use `example.com` as the domain), but you can fix it by adding the `http://` yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Blckknght You are amazing. that was the whole problem. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

The whole problem was a missing `http://` in the urlretrieve link... I have spent almost 10 hours trying to solve that problem using wget and other methods, and @Blckknght just solved it for me. =)

I wish you all the best, have a great day
-CodingCode.